# Creating Table and Graph of Means in R

Tags: r, graph, mean, errorbar

I'm trying to create a table and graph with standard error bars for my data. However, I'm not sure how to go about it. I'm using this code to get the means of my variables:

```
tapply(Rhino$Total.browse.m.cubed, Rhino$Description, myFun)   
cbind(Description = unique(Rhino$Description), 
do.call(rbind, tapply(Rhino$Total.browse.m.cubed, Rhino$Description, myFun)))
```

However, I'm not sure how to make this into a table with all of the data (`min`, `max`, `mean` etc) and a graph of just means with standard error bars.

```
Description           min       max          mean         median      std
Wooded Grassland      11        6155.705717  6155.70572   6155.70572  6155.7057    NA
Airstrip Grassland     6        711.843443   711.84344    711.84344   711.84344    NA
Euclea bush           15        2395.830066  22403.46446  9304.55141  6269.08369   8283.5034
etc......
```

Comment: Please, provide a reproducible example and show desired output. Read to create an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: is you output a data frame? if not just format it as a data frame and you should be able to plot what you want

Comment: Check this tutorial https://morevine.wordpress.com/2010/05/06/statistics-with-r-barplots-with-errorbars/. It is using the `errbar()` function from the Hmisc package.